Issue: JSObjectGetPrototype Returns the Same JSValueRef for Different Classes
In JavaScriptCore, when creating and manipulating classes and prototypes, the JSObjectGetPrototype function is used to retrieve the prototype of an object.
Problem:
I’ve encountered a situation where JSObjectGetPrototype always returns the same JSValueRef for different classes, even though I am creating distinct prototypes for each class.

I create multiple classes, each with its own unique prototype.
When I use JSObjectGetPrototype to retrieve the prototype of different instances, I receive the  same JSValueRef for all of them, suggesting that the prototype is not unique as expected.

What I Tried:

Creating Unique Prototypes:

I used JSObjectMake to create new objects as prototypes for different classes.
I then called JSObjectSetPrototype to set these prototypes for the respective constructors.


Retrieving and Logging Prototypes:

I used JSObjectGetPrototype to retrieve the prototype for each class instance.
I logged the addresses of the prototypes to verify their uniqueness.


Logging and Comparison:

I compared the addresses of the prototypes retrieved for different classes to check if they were unique.



What I Expected:

Unique Prototypes:

I expected that each class would have its own unique prototype.
The addresses retrieved by JSObjectGetPrototype for different classes should be distinct.


Access to Methods:

I anticipated that methods added to the prototypes would be accessible when interacting with instances of these classes.



Outcome:

Despite setting different prototypes for each class, JSObjectGetPrototype returned the same JSValueRef for all classes.
This suggests that the prototypes are not being set or managed correctly, resulting in all classes sharing the same prototype.

Questions:

Is there a known issue or limitation with JSObjectGetPrototype returning the same value for all classes?
How can I ensure that prototypes are correctly assigned and are unique for each class?
Are there any additional steps or considerations to manage prototypes effectively in JavaScriptCore?


Can you post a simple sample code of how the classes are created and how you access them with JSObjectGetPrototype?

Is it possible that you have accessed Object.getPrototypeOf(someClass), which is Function.prototype for most classes, instead of Object.getPrototypeOf(someInstance)? If you're working with a class reference, you need to use someClass.prototype!

The problem is that no matter what i give to the JSObjectGetPrototype it always return the same value reference.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jsobjectgetprototype(::)?language=objc

Again, if you are calling that on the class object itself, it's expected that it always returns the same Function.prototype object

when i call console.log(CLASS_NAME) i get the prototype  which contain all functions, but when i try that after i created new instance with 'new' i got empty object without that prototype.

Again, please [edit] your question to post the exact code you're running.
